# AWS Quicksight embedded dashboard .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, quicksight-embedding, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to embed dashboards on our company's site. I'm using .NET Core 2.1 and AWSSDK 3.3.1.12
We're running our site on AWS Lambda using API Gateway.

I've followed this 2 guides to set up permissions and set up an endpoint to get the Embed the Dashboard URL

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-analytics-dashboards-for-authenticated-users.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/

I have managed to get the embed dashboard URL

```
var getDashboardUrl = await client.GetDashboardEmbedUrlAsync(new GetDashboardEmbedUrlRequest
                {
                    AwsAccountId = awsAccountId,
                    IdentityType = EmbeddingIdentityType.QUICKSIGHT,
                    DashboardId = testDashboardId,
                    SessionLifetimeInMinutes = 100,
                    ResetDisabled = true,
                    UndoRedoDisabled = false,
                    Namespace = "default",
                    UserArn = $"arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:{awsAccountId}:user/default/{email}",
                    StatePersistenceEnabled = true
                });
```

And used the Quicksight javascript SDK to embed the dashboard but I'm getting an error. It shows that is loading the dashboard but once loaded shows a message "**We can't display this page (Not authorized)**"

[Error message that I get on our site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/810AL.png)

```
function embedDashboard(embedUrl) {
    let containerDiv = document.getElementById("embeddingContainer");
    let options = {
        // replace this dummy url with the one generated via embedding API
        url: embedUrl,
        container: containerDiv,
        scrolling: "no",
        height: "700px",
        width: "1000px",
        footerPaddingEnabled: true
    };
    dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(options);
}
```

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the url is being encoded in some way. A common issue is the ampersand (&) character being escaped when passing the url string to the embedding script.

```
...&identityprovider=quicksight&isauthcode=true
```

can be passed as

```
...&amp;identityprovider=quicksight&amp;isauthcode=true
```

This causes the embed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have permissions to see the dashboard, is needed a https connection to render the dashboard.

So check you user in quicksight can see and view the in quicksight and allow a domain or ip with https for render your dashboard

Sources Documentation

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/enabling-ip-restrictions.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-for-authenticated-users-get-step-1.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/share-a-dashboard-grant-access-users.html
4. https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/embedding-amazon-quicksight-analytics-in-net-applications/

Comment: please attach supporting DOC